# Can you define a complexity class by giving a language and declaring that the language is complete for the class?

Tags: complexity-classes

Can I define a complexity class $\mathsf{C}$ by giving a language $L^\prime$ and stating that $L^\prime$ is $\mathsf C$-complete? Specifically, a language $L$ is in $\mathsf C$ if there is a reduction from $L$ to $L^\prime$.

If so, are there any common (i.e., well-studied) complexity classes that are usually defined this way? If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, complexity classes can be defined this way. $GI$ is a well-studied example. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#Complexity_class_GI):

> Since the graph isomorphism problem is neither known to be $NP$-complete nor known to be tractable, researchers have sought to gain insight into the problem by defining a new class $GI$, the set of problems with a polynomial-time Turing reduction to the graph isomorphism problem.